# Camera App iOS memory usage

Tags: ios, memory, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, alassetslibrary

I'm making a camera app in iOS. Everything is fine except from the memory usage. This is the flow of the "takeImageTask":

`AVCaptureStillImageOutput` -> `NSData` -> `UIImage` (which I crop and do other changes to) -> save to `ALAssetsLibrary`

I need to keep the `UIImage` in an array because I need to have them in a `UICollectionView`, and I have the possibility to show the images in a "big size" view.

This flow uses a lot of memory, so what I thought could be a better solution was to use the `AssetURL` I get from the `AVCaptureStillImageOutput writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum` to fetch the images from the phone storage. My app also have the possibility to fetch images from the photo album by using `UIImagePickerController`, and I've noticed that this just uses a fraction of the memory compared to the "takeImageTask". I first made the app as an Android version, and there I just stored all the URLs, and used them to present images. Does anyone have any experience using asseturls to present images in iOS?

Comment: I have used AssetURL and its good way to store & retrieve images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to keep the UIImage in an array because I need to have them in a UICollectionView, and I have the possibility to show the images in a "big size" view.

This is flawed logic. You might want to keep a minimal size thumbnail image in memory for the collection view, but you should even drop these from memory before the count gets too big. And the big images should be loaded from disk on demand because it is relatively infrequent and relatively expensive (using the asset URL is a good plan for this).

Comment: "This is flawed logic", yeah, that was what I thought, and this is what I evaded on the Android version (storing just the paths). So, I've to take a closer look at the AssetsLibrary. What I've already looked at, considering the AssetsLibrary, seems quite troublesome, with all the async, callbacks and stuff, compared with the android-way of doing it where you just can use FileOutputStream, but I'm sure I'll manage it. Examples using AssetsLibrary in CollectionView is appreciated.

Comment: The callbacks are run on the main thread so the only thing to worry about really is using the right image size and ensuring that the cell is still associated with the same index path when you come to add the image to it.